# Blogdown/Xaringan does not work after using chakra option

Tags: r-markdown, blogdown, xaringan, remarkjs

I followed the installation process for Xaringan explained by [Tim Mastny](https://timmastny.rbind.io/blog/embed-slides-knitr-blogdown/). Everything worked smoothly and I could produce my first slideshow.

To make the slides work offline, I followed the tips by [Yihui Xie](https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#32). The download with `xaringan::summon_remark()` went fine and generated the `libs` folder in my project directory with the file `remark-latest.min.js` in it. But when I added the chakra option `chakra: libs/remark-latest.min.js` to the YAML header as describe in the Xaringan slideshow documenation, and called `serve_site()`, the slideshow did not work anymore.

Instead of the previous working slideshow I got a small window on the left top of my screen which contains the source text of my slideshow. I have seen this window in other occassions as well. For instance in some links from the remark.js website to demo slideshows, e.g. [here](https://gnab.github.io/js-workshop/).

I installed a complete new blogdown website with the Xmin theme and did the installation procedure from scratch. I used the R Markdown "Nina Presentation" template and added just the one chakra line. I received the same result. Just the small window.

I used Google Chrome but tested also with Safari and Firefox with the same result. Has anyone any idea what could be the problem or what I could try next?

My sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.5.1  backports_1.1.2 bookdown_0.7    magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2 htmltools_0.3.6
 [7] tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.1.19     Rcpp_0.12.17    stringi_1.2.4   rmarkdown_1.10  blogdown_0.8   
[13] knitr_1.20      xfun_0.3        stringr_1.3.1   digest_0.6.15   evaluate_0.11
```

Comment: I believe you don't need to explicitly specify `chakra` in the YAML. Could you provide your slide rmd file(in a github repo maybe?). Another thing,  `blogdown` has nothing to do with xaringan slides.

Comment: Thank you @TC-Zhang for clarifying the no-relationship blogdown-xaringan. My repo with this problematic commit is at https://github.com/petzi53/weblog-portfolio/tree/blog  and my live test deployment at https://5b5432b2792f8973022e957d--thought-splinters.netlify.com/slide/xaringan-error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem: you summoned remark.js to `libs/` in your blogdown project's root directory. Instead, you should summon remark.js to `static/slide/libs/` using:

```
xaringan::summon_remark(to = "static/slide/libs")
```

Explaination: Hugo copies all files under "static/" to the root of the compiled website.

Make sure `libs/` sits together with your xaringan source Rmd somewhere under `static/` subdirectory, like yours: `static/slide/libs`, so that the xaringan can find files they need.

And that `remark-latest-min.js` should be in `static/slide/libs/` too.